# How to apply a basic vector to physics body in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, sprite, physics

I am making a very simple space game; I can't seem to get the last line to work. Ideally, I want to get the spacey to move to up when the screen is touched. Here is my code:

```
func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        touch.locationInNode(self)

        spacey.physicsBody!.velocity = (CGVectorMake(0, 0))

        spacey.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(0, atPoint: 25)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Should your point be an integer? `spacey.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(0, atPoint: 25)`

Comment: I have tried a double and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
   /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in touches {
        _ = touch.locationInNode(self)

        spacey.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
        spacey.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 25))
```

The solution was to change touch in touches to use _ in swift 2.0

Comment: The `_ =` does absolutely nothing in this case. You changed the `applyImpulse(0, atPoint: 25)` to `applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 25))` which fixed your problem ;)